Could it be possible to matain backup on local server
Can data be inserted into the live database as well as the database on the local server through the live application at the same time?
My aim is maintain backup at local server.

The short answer is probably yes, but it's not really a Drupal question, it's more of a network configuration question, which unfortunately is out of the scope of Drupal answers.
